# Are there analogues to the Mormon/LDS high school seminary in other Christian denominations?

Tags: religious-education

The LDS church has a [high school seminary system](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Church_Educational_System#Seminaries) where high school students intensively learn the teachings of the LDS church.  This is a week-daily 1/2hr - 1 hour class taken before normal school hours and then the kids go to their highschool.  Do such systems exist for those in other Christian denominations?

Comment: Most students do attend before school in the mornings, but in highly-Mormon-populated areas (Utah, Arizona, etc), they have "release-time" seminary, where a seminary class during the day actually counts toward school credit. More official information about the LDS seminary program: http://seminary.lds.org/

Comment: Many private Christian and Catholic schools offer the same sort of thing for enrolled students.

Comment: Remember also that the LDS churches expects all males to preach and be priests.  The Protestant notion of "the priesthood of all believers" is not that at all...

Comment: Mormons would say that they are not a Christian "denomination," just FYI.

Answer (score 2):

There is World of Life and Torchbearer do something like it in the evangelical circles.

- World of life : http://www.wol.org
- Torchebearer : http://torchbearers.org